# Numpy Installation: How do I fix the broken toolchain without Bash and limited permissions?

Tags: python, windows, numpy, permissions, cmd

Preface: I am a Mac/Unix user and am now a little lost with Windows.

Situation: I am trying to use python on a school machine that has a 64-bit architecture and running Windows 7.  I have gotten the module NetworkX to work via `python setup.py install`, but need the numerical libraries to be available as well.

Question: I have the identical output as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15734338/how-to-install-numpy-1-8-dev-on-windows) elaborates and need to install numpy with correct dependencies.  How do I do this with limited permissions?

Problems: The solution in the above link cannot be adopted in my case.  I do not have Visual Studio 2008 and cannot install it due to permissions. Also, the linear algebra library that is required costs 500$, which frankly is a deal breaker.  I thought I could adopt this SO [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22388519/problems-with-pip-install-numpy-runtimeerror-broken-toolchain-cannot-link-a), but I do not have access to Bash.  I also cannot run `.exe` files due to permissions.  All the modules I have installed have been using `python setup.py install`.  Any help or suggestions are VERY much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you install one of the scientific python distributions like Anaconda or Canopy?  That might include everything you need. See http://scipy.org/install.html for a list of options.

Comment: Funny... I downloaded a .zip file of the Anaconda distribution of SciPy Stack.  From this, I could run the .exe file after copying to my \C: drive.  Not sure if Windows was duped by this sequence of events or I am missing something myself.  Anyways, now I can use IPython and edit scripts using Notepad.  Thank you, Aric!